# How to use JNA in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, jna

I downloaded jna.jar and I added it to my project, and I'm getting errors such as com.sun.jna does not exist, and I think the reason why my project doesn't work is because I can't import com.sun.jna.Native and the others.
Can someone please tell me how can I fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your netbeans logs.  Netbeans uses a version of JNA itself, so you may need to [work around that](http://praxisintermedia.wordpress.com/2012/01/04/jna-3-4-0-on-the-netbeans-platform/).

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar problem myself and found that I needed to add the jar files to the Compile-time libraries.  This automatically adds it to the run-time libraries.  It's likely you only added the libraries as run time libraries, but not compile-time.

To do this you can do `Project->Project Properties` then select `Libraries`.  On the Compile tab, click `Add JAR/Folder` for each library (`jna-4.1.0.jar` and `jna-platform-4.1.0.jar`, for example.)
After clicking OK, your compile errors should go away.

If you plan to use JNA in several projects, create a new library in Tools Libraries.  Click on New Library...  Type in JNA in the Library Name.  In the Classpath tab, add the two .jar files by clicking on Add JAR/Folder...  Click OK.  To add the files to each project, then simply Project->Project Properties and Select Libraries.  In the Compile tab simply click on Add Library... and select your new "JNA" library.  Click OK.  You'll see your JNA `.jars` as two stack of books icons under Libraries in the Projects view.